# update in nested_forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using Rails 3.0.3
I have a Model Bill:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :entries    
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries

end
```

In my Bill view i am using nested forms to create new entries in bills and with Javascript i insert existing entries with at this point, have no bill_id:

```
$("#row" + nested_form_id).append("<input type='hidden' name='bill[entries_attributes][" + nested_form_id + "][id]' id='bill_entries_attributes_" + nested_form_id + "_id' value='" + id +"' >");
```

when i submit the form i get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Entry with ID=127 for Bill with ID=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:121:in `new'
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:121:in `create'
```

so the problem is, that rails is looking for the entry in bills when i submit

any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt figure out how this is possible with nested forms, so i set the entries which allready exists manually to the bill:

```
nested_entries = {}      
params[:bill][:entries_attributes] = {}  


params[:entries].each_pair do |key, value|    
   if value[:id].nil?
      params[:bill][:entries_attributes][key] = value 
   else 
     nested_entries[key] = value
   end                             
end           

@bill = Bill.new(params[:bill])  
@bill.save  

bill_id = @bill.id        

nested_entries.each_pair do |key, value|   
   @entry = Entry.find(value[:id])    
   value[:bill_id] = bill_id                            
   @entry.update_attributes(value) 
end
```